# \pgfplotsset causes Error in combination with fill between or pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I want to do several plots in a .tex document and I don't want to set the linestyle for each line seperate. so I used '\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={mark=*, mark size=2pt, line width=1pt, }}' to set the style in the complete document. Now, I want to add fill betweens but the command \pgfplotsset causes an error in combination with fill between. Following a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgf} %Grafikpakete
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={mark=*, mark size=2pt, line width=1pt, }}

\begin{figure}[b!]
    \begin{adjustbox}{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{groupplot}[
                group style = {group size = 1 by 1,
                    horizontal sep=4mm,
                    vertical sep=4mm,},
                height = 0.8*2.5in,
                width = 0.6*3.0in,
                ]
                \nextgroupplot[
                clip mode=individual,
                ]
                \addplot[name path = A, ]  coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
                \addplot[name path = B, ]  coordinates {(1,1) (2,2)};
                \addplot[name path = C, ]  coordinates {(2,1) (3,2)};
                \addplot[name path = D, ]  coordinates {(3,1) (4,2)};
                
                
                
                \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B, on layer=behindlayer]{ pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)},line width=1pt]}, pattern color=green, opacity=0.25};
                \addplot [red, opacity=0.25, ] fill between [of = B and C];
                \addplot [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt/sqrt(2)},line width=1pt]}, pattern color=blue] fill between [of = C and D];
                
            \end{groupplot}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get this working? If not, can I define a style variable which I can put in the add plot options like this:

```
line_style = {mark=*, mark size=2pt, line width=1pt, }

...

\addplot[line_style, name path = A, ]  coordinates {(0,1) (1,2)};
```